# Magento 1.9.1 when i update Patch SUPEE 6788 then cannot see products in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, supee-6788

Magento 1.9.1 when i update Patch SUPEE 6788 then cannot see products in static block but text appear in static block please tell me what should i do

Answer (score 1):

The latest patch adds some more security features to your Magento webshop. One of these features is that (some, often custom designed) blocks need security clearance added in the backend. Go to System > Permissions > Blocks. Simply added the folder structure to allow it to show in the frontend. So if your block is located in the "template/catalog/mycustomblock" folder, simply add catalog/mycustomblock as block name set "is allowed" to yes and you're all set!

Answer (score 0):

Since the update you need to approve custom blocks

https://www.pinpointdesigns.co.uk/blog/magento-ce-patch-supee-6788-custom-blocks-issue/